# Prometheus Unit test of Gauge value in Golang

Tags: go, testing, prometheus

I have a function that calculates a value and then, using a Prometheus gauge variable, it is saved (or at least prepared to be scraped) in Prometheus. So setup looks like this:

```
// Prometheus variable: Enclosure Ambient Temperature.
    errorLog = prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Name: "Encoded_Messages",
        Help: "Encoded system info/warning/error messages",
    })
```

In my function, the value is finally saved to the DB as follows:

```
errorLog.Set(float64(123)) // Capture message to database
```

For clarity, I have replaced the (calculated) variable with 123. As my value is calculated, it should be (theoretically) easy enough to verify that the value saved to the database (or at least made ready to scrape) is in fact 123.

There is no issue with the primary function, however now I wish to write a unit test to test said function. I have many other (non tested) functions already working and data successfully being scraped, but I need to create unit tests for those too.

During the unit test I don't want any spurious data being saved to the database, so really there needs to be a means of mocking the HTML scraper page, correct?

I have looked at some options such as what is mentioned here:
[Unit test using golang prometheus testutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911468/unit-test-using-golang-prometheus-testutil)

I have also read through the utilities provided for Prometheus here:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/testutil?utm_source=godoc#CollectAndCompare
Unfortunately no examples are given. I think maybe that the "CollectAndCompare" is what I need, but I have been unable to get this working.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the text output (the same as you get at your /metrics endpoint) as a Reader

Here is my test for some data that is pulled from a database

```golang
func TestCollect(t *testing.T) {

// setup dummy test data
    fetchFromDB = func() (ok bool, voltage float64, temp float64, power float64, frequency float64, etoday float64) {
        return true, 123.1, 99.0, 567.8, 55.5, 789.0
    }
    collector := newCollector()
    ch := make(chan prometheus.Metric)
    go collector.Collect(ch)

    expected := strings.NewReader(
        `# HELP voltage voltage
# TYPE voltage gauge
voltage 123.1
# HELP EToday Total Power today Wh
# TYPE EToday gauge
EToday 789.0
# HELP Frequency AC Frequency
# TYPE Frequency gauge
Frequency 55.5
# HELP Power power
# TYPE Power gauge
Power 567.8
# HELP Temperature temp
# TYPE Temperature gauge
Temperature 99.0
`)
    err := testutil.CollectAndCompare(collector, expected, "voltage", "EToday", "Frequency", "Temperature", "Power")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s", err.Error())
    }

}
```

There are some good examples of testing in the source code

https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/v1.14.0/prometheus/testutil/testutil_test.go#L125